# unable to write the data from selectbox into the data base, ("empty data")

Tags: php, mysql, html

He Guys, does any one knows how te selove this problem?
php doesn't see the selected data and giving my the error that something is empty after pressing the submitButton

MY CODE:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../connections/dbc.php';
$product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['product_name']);
if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['product_name'])) {
        $sql=" INSERT INTO `order`(`product_name`) VALUES('$product_name');";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (!$result) {
            echo "ERROR INSERTING THE ORDER IN THE DATABASE";
        }
    }   else{
        echo "EMPTY";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST SITE</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form method="POST">
      <select>
         <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" style="text-align: center;">--SELECT--</option>
<?php
    require_once '../connections/dbc.php';
    $query = "SELECT `product_name` FROM `product`";
    $response = @mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (!$response) {
        echo "NO RESPONES";
    }   else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
            echo '<option name="product_name" value="'.$row['product_name'].'" >'.$row['product_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }
?>
</select>
<button name="submitButton" id="submitButton"></button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `name="product_name"` should be on the `select` not the `option`

Comment: LOOOOOOLLLLLL IM SO STUPID 
Thank you very much